# Controlling Python package versions

Tags: python, svn, pip

So I am staring down a situation and I am hoping you good people might have some suggestions about how to address it with minimal complexity.

I am maintaining a small lab that does its development in Python.  All of our users are internal but maintain their own machines.  Our own source files are kept in SVN, but our various dependencies are stored on a lab wiki for download.   For the first time in many years we are looking at updating our dependency versions and I would like to find something a bit cleaner then 'copy installer or egg from website, store on lab ftp, tell users to get it from there'.

Our internal users tend to be non-technical, which is why the old setup was just a bunch of installers sitting around.  This has its own problems though, it is a pain to maintain (esp in terms of minor updates), you have to grab separate installers for each OS, and not all packages have nice .exe installers ready to go so users have to install some packages one way and other packages another way.  Not a problem for developers but it is not great for users.

For things like RPMs, in the past, I have been able to throw together a local repo and provide users with something they install once and then all their updates go through the repo we controlled.  This has worked great in terms of users not getting annoyed by complexity and developers having strict control over which versions of various libs they have installed.

I looked around and saw questions that kinda touched on this, but nothing that quite addressed this type of problem.  Are there any quick and dirty ways to do something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I've struggled with this in previous roles, but on my team in more recent years, Poetry has become a standard for managing versions in Python. Or more specifically as a dependency management and packaging tool designed to help structure a project.

- **Dependency Resolution:** Poetry is pretty great at resolving complex dependency trees.  It determines compatible versions for all your project's requirements and tries to minimize conflicts.
- **Version Locking:** it creates a `poetry.lock` file to store the exact versions of all installed packages and their dependencies. This lock file ensures reproducible environments across different systems or for future use. It's saved my sanity a few times.
- **Version Constraints:** Like `requirements.txt`, Poetry allows us to specify version constraints within the `pyproject.toml` file:

  - `^1.2.3` (Caret): Compatible updates (1.2.3, 1.2.4, ... 1.9.9)
  - `~=1.2.3`  (Tilde): Minor updates (1.2.3, 1.2.4, ... 1.2.9)
  - `>1.2.0`, `<2.0.0` (Greater than/less than): More flexible ranges
- **Virtual Environments:** Poetry seamlessly handles the creation and management of project-specific virtual environments.

Install with pip and follow the init instructions and you're good to go.

Comment: Although this is an old question I thought it needed answering as I struggled with this too until joining my current team and discovering how we use Poetry. Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently handling a similar situation with

- devpi as a pypi cache that also supports local uploads
- pip as the installer
- wheels as the packaging format
- virtualenv to deal with python versioning (you may not need this part).

Various internal projects are versioned in setup.py and built into wheels.

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
devpi login username
devpi use http:/someserver:3141/user/repo_index
devpi upload dist/whatever
```

I have a pip requirements file on the network and users have a `pip.conf` file that points to the devpi server. Users update packages with

```
pip install -U http://someserver/requirements_file
```